# Why is there no Directory class?

Tags: java

The File class contains methods that are applicable only to directories and just return null for regular files.  Why are they not defined as separate classes sharing an abstract parent?

Comment: This calls for speculation, which is ["not constructive" on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask). (Unless, of course, the original author of that code is kicking around and can tell us, for sure, why. Or someone has a link to a place where the author has already done that. Both seem fairly unlikely to me.)

Comment: Not constructive. Anyway: remember that a `File` object does not exactly correspond to our concept of a "file" (or directory) but rather to a pathname.

Comment: A directory is really a special kind of file. Perhaps there could have been an additional abstraction for `Directory`, but you would have to ask the authors why. IMO, I feel like it would be an unnecessary distinction.

Comment: Not constructive for SO. But, its kicking some thought process on +1

Comment: Because directory can be "treated" as a file having the pointers to the files with in it and to the parent directory